# Secondary name node is not displaying when I hit JPS command

Tags: hadoop

I have Hadoop-3.1.3 and I can upload a file in hadoop pseudo distributed mode, also can display the contents of file.

but when I call jps command i am getting the following output

```
10912 DataNode
13072 ResourceManager
4480 NodeManager
6584 Jps
664 Namenode
```

I am unable to find secondary name node, is there a problem with any configuration or hadoop installation?

Answer (score 0):

You're assuming that secondary namenode is started with psuedo-distributed?

If the basic commands work, then its fine.

You need to look at log files to know if something is broken, before asking elsewhere....

---

In general, [I always suggest you use Apache Ambari to provision a Hadoop cluster](https://www.thoughtworks.com/radar/techniques/handcranking-of-hadoop-clusters-using-config-management-tools)

Answer (score 0):

You can start the Secondary NameNode manually and observe the start up logs to see if there's anything wrong:

```
hdfs secondarynamenode
```

If there's no error, run `jps` again and hopefully you see SecondaryNameNode listed.

---

I'd suggest running `hdfs --help` and checking out all of the options, there's a lot of good stuff there.